# Is it possible to use two stop words dictionaries in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

I'm trying to get a list of most frequent words appearing in a column.

```
SELECT
  word,
  sum(nentry) AS nentry
FROM ts_stat(
  $$
    SELECT to_tsvector('simple', body)
    FROM document
  $$
)
GROUP BY word
```

This works pretty well, but the problem is that documents contain words in French and English. If I use the English dictionary for stop words, the most frequent word I get is `pour`, and it's `the` when I use the French one. Those are two words I obviously want to exclude.

Is there a way to create a configuration that uses two different dictionaries for stop words ?

Comment: Have you looked at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-createtsdictionary.html

Comment: Yes, I did. The problem lies in the fact that you can only choose one stop word file.
I could create a new stop word file, but it's a PITA for deployment. We use Heroku, and I have no idea if it is even possible to alter the filesystem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should create a stop word file that is the union of the French and English stop word files and create a `simple` dictionary with that stop word file.

Then create a text search configuration that uses this dictionary for `asciiword` and `word` and use this configuration.